# Mostrar dias de acceso agrupandolos por personal

Tags: php, mysqli

quisiera pedirles su ayuda para obtener las diferentes fechas de asistencias que hacen el personal de una empresa.

Tengo una consulta que me muestra mis datos asi:

```
|nombre|primer_apellido|segundo_apellido|  hour  | dir |   date   |
|:-----|:-------------:|:--------------:|:------:|:---:|---------:|
|Pablo |Perez          |Perez           |07:50:06|Tic´s|2022-11-16|
|Pablo |Perez          |Perez           |08:50:06|Tic´s|2022-11-17|
```

El cual la consulta MYSQL es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
    p.nombre,
    p.primer_apellido,
    p.segundo_apellido,
    a.`hour`,
    c.nombre AS dir,
    a.date 
FROM
    asistencias.attendance a
    INNER JOIN personal.personal p ON a.employee_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN personal.ads_personal ad ON p.id = ad.idPersonal
    INNER JOIN personal.catdireccion c ON ad.idDireccion = c.id 
WHERE
    MONTH ( a.date ) = 11
```

Sin embargo, lo que busco es que la consulta sea agrupada por el personal y que me muestre las diferentes fechas de asistencia

Intente hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
 p.nombre,
 p.primer_apellido,
 p.segundo_apellido,
 a.`hour`,
 c.nombre AS dir,
 a.date 
FROM
 asistencias.attendance a
 INNER JOIN personal.personal p ON a.employee_id = p.id
 INNER JOIN personal.ads_personal ad ON p.id = ad.idPersonal
 INNER JOIN personal.catdireccion c ON ad.idDireccion = c.id 
WHERE
 MONTH ( a.date ) = 11 GROUP BY p.id
```

Pero lo que hace es que solo me muestra el primer registro que encuentra, y no me muestra los demas, ejemplo:

```
|nombre|primer_apellido|segundo_apellido|  hour  | dir |   date   |
|:-----|:-------------:|:--------------:|:------:|:---:|---------:|
|Pablo |Perez          |Perez           |07:50:06|Tic´s|2022-11-16|
```

Quisiera que me mostrara los demás registros, sin embargo no encuentro como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la función de agregación `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Te dejo aquí parte de la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) (ver ejemplos de código en el enlace):

> Esta función devuelve un resultado de cadena con los valores no `NULL`
> concatenados de un grupo. Devuelve `NULL` si no hay valores que no
> sean `NULL`.
>
> En MySQL, puede obtener los valores concatenados de combinaciones de
> expresiones. Para eliminar valores duplicados, utilice la cláusula
> `DISTINCT`. Para ordenar valores en el resultado, use la cláusula
> `ORDER BY`. Para ordenar en orden inverso, agregue la palabra clave
> `DESC` (descendente) al nombre de la columna por la que está ordenando
> en la cláusula `ORDER BY`. El valor predeterminado es el orden
> ascendente; esto se puede especificar explícitamente usando la palabra
> clave `ASC`. El separador predeterminado entre los valores de un grupo
> es la coma (`,`). Para especificar un separador de forma explícita,
> use `SEPARATOR` seguido del valor literal de la cadena que debe
> insertarse entre los valores del grupo. Para eliminar el separador por
> completo, especifique `SEPARATOR ''`.
>
> El resultado se trunca a la longitud máxima proporcionada por la
> variable de sistema `group_concat_max_len`, que tiene un valor
> predeterminado de `1024`. El valor se puede establecer más alto,
> aunque la longitud máxima efectiva del valor devuelto está restringida
> por el valor de `max_allowed_packet`. La sintaxis para cambiar el
> valor de `group_concat_max_len` en tiempo de ejecución es la
> siguiente, donde `val` es un entero sin signo:
>
> ```
> SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
> ```

Por ejemplo, si quieres un grupo con los valores de `hour` y otro con los valores de `date`:

```
SELECT
 p.nombre,
 p.primer_apellido,
 p.segundo_apellido,
 GROUP_CONCAT(a.`hour`) AS hours,
 GROUP_CONCAT(a.`date`) AS dates, 
 c.nombre AS dir
FROM
 asistencias.attendance a
 INNER JOIN personal.personal p ON a.employee_id = p.id
 INNER JOIN personal.ads_personal ad ON p.id = ad.idPersonal
 INNER JOIN personal.catdireccion c ON ad.idDireccion = c.id 
WHERE
 MONTH ( a.`date` ) = 11 
GROUP BY 
 p.id,
 p.nombre,
 p.primer_apellido,
 p.segundo_apellido,
 c.nombre;
```

O, si quieres un grupo combinando `hour` y `date` (por cierto, debiste haber definido una sola columna del tipo `DATETIME`, así te ahorras un columna y te ahorras esto) puedes usar `GROUP_CONCAT` con `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
 p.nombre,
 p.primer_apellido,
 p.segundo_apellido,
 GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.`date`,' ',a.`hour`)) AS hours,
 c.nombre AS dir
FROM
 asistencias.attendance a
 INNER JOIN personal.personal p ON a.employee_id = p.id
 INNER JOIN personal.ads_personal ad ON p.id = ad.idPersonal
 INNER JOIN personal.catdireccion c ON ad.idDireccion = c.id 
WHERE
 MONTH ( a.`date` ) = 11 
GROUP BY 
 p.id,
 p.nombre,
 p.primer_apellido,
 p.segundo_apellido,
 c.nombre;
```

Pero OJO a lo que dice la doc: *Devuelve `NULL` si no hay valores que no sean `NULL`*. Si `hours` o `date` no tiene restricción `NOT NULL`, debes controlar los posibles nulos, o todo será nulo. Para ello puedes usar `COALESCE`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT
 p.nombre,
 p.primer_apellido,
 p.segundo_apellido,
 GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(COALESCE(a.`date`,''),' ', COALESCE (a.`hour`,''))) AS dates_hours,
 c.nombre AS dir
FROM
 asistencias.attendance a
 INNER JOIN personal.personal p ON a.employee_id = p.id
 INNER JOIN personal.ads_personal ad ON p.id = ad.idPersonal
 INNER JOIN personal.catdireccion c ON ad.idDireccion = c.id 
WHERE
 MONTH ( a.`date` ) = 11 
GROUP BY 
 p.id,
 p.nombre,
 p.primer_apellido,
 p.segundo_apellido,
 c.nombre;
```

Con esto:

```
COALESCE(a.`date`,'')
```

si en algún caso el valor de `a.date` es `NULL`, será reemplazado por un valor en blanco, claro está que en vez de `''` puedes poner lo que quieras entre las comillas simples.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, me funciono muy bien @A. Cedano